# SQL Delete using joins

Tags: oracle, sql-delete, oracle8i

I am trying to delete rows from both emp and dept tables using the below query.
But after the query executed, it is deleting rows from only dept table and not from emp.

```
delete  (
select * from  emp e,dept d
where e.empno=d.empno
and  e.sal in  ('200','1950','5000')
and d.objid in ('1001','1002','1003')
);
```

I am using oracle 8i.
Please help!!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Oracle only allows deleting from one table per statement, AFAIK.  So, you should rewrite your logic to do two separate deletes.

Comment: Or, you could setup on cascade deleting, so you'd only have to delete records from the parent table.